# Sharepoint online site collection setup best practices

Tags: search, sharepoint-online, site-collection

The scenario is something like this, we need to setup a site collection infra in SharePoint online which needs to hold ~30Tb of data (mostly docs). We need to set up a search service in there that crawls through all these docs. My questions :

1. What are the best practices for setting up a site collection infrastructure online that can support large scale data (~30TB)
2. What is the best approach for configuring a search solution (out of the box SharePoint) that can crawl through such a large amount of data efficiently.

Links to relevant discussions, guides, articles etc. would be great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First of all, you can only hold up to 1TB in Site Collections on SharePoint Online. (http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/sharepoint-online-software-boundaries-and-limits-HA102694293.aspx)

Comment: @z.rahui so I need to have at least 30 Site Collections

Comment: In terms of 'Search Efficiency', you don't really have any control of how the Search engine crawls your content in SharePoint online. It will really come down to how your content is presented in SharePoint. Using keywords, terms, content types etc. That way will give you more control over how you can construct your search queries. You would most likely benefit from a data migration tool (such as ShareGate or DocAve) to move and tag content into SharePoint in a bulk manner.

Comment: Should I follow any best practices towards setting up my sharepoint environment (like implementing site collections) so that my searching would be more efficient.